# Need help with the integral $\int_{0}^\infty e^{-x^{2}}x^{2n+1}dx $

Tags: calculus, integration, definite-integrals, improper-integrals

Problem: Prove that $$I = \int_{0}^\infty  e^{-x^{2}}x^{2n+1}dx = \frac{n!}{2}     $$

Source: A problem I found on an integral test. The problem bugged me for long and I did end up leaving it on the exam. Back home I decided to tackle it again. Here's my go on it.

My try: I have never encountered such a problem before, not even in my assignments and workbooks. Here's how I tried it

We can first take an **indefinite integral** and then we can work up towards a **reduction formula**.We can plug in the limits later. I don't know if it's any good but I did write this up on the exam: $$I_{2n+1} = \int{e^{x^{-2}}}{x^{2n+1}}dx$$

On applying Integration by parts:

$$I_{2n+1} = e^{-x^{2}}\frac{x^{2n+2}}{2n+2} +\frac{2}{2n+2} \int{e^{-x^{2}}}{x^{2n+3}}dx$$

or $$I_{2n+1} = e^{-x^{2}}\frac{x^{2n+2}}{2n+2} +\frac{I_{2n+3}}{n+1} $$
or

$$I_{2n+1} = {e^{-x^{2}}\over 2}\Bigl(\frac{x^{2n+2}}{n+1}\Bigl) +\frac{I_{2n+3}}{n+1} $$

What can I do next? Am I doing it incorrectly? Is this the wrong way? Please help me as I can't stop thinking about this problem! Thanks!

**Edit 1:** As suggested (already tried by me) lets put $u = -x^2$
$$ du = -2xdx$$
plug the above expression in the problem

$$I_{n} = -{1 \over 2}\int{e^{u}}{u^{n}}du$$

$$I_{n} = -{1 \over 2}e^{-u}\frac{u^{n+1}}{n+1} + \frac{I_(n+1)}{n+1}$$

Certainly helps. Now what?

**Edit 2:** Use the [gamma function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gamma_function) to get the result. Now unfortunately I didn't read it for the test that's why I didn't get it. Thank you all for pointing out the right direction!

Comment: $$e^{x^{-2}}$$ or $$e^{-x^2}\ ?$$

Comment: The latter is the arch classical Gaussian integral. Tons of questions about it here.

Comment: I'm very sorry I'll correct it now @Did thanks for pointing out

Comment: Try the substitution $t = x^2$ on your initial integral

Comment: First to simplify perform the change of variable $y=x^2$

Comment: After the substitution that has been suggested, it may be possible to rewrite the integral as (or using) the gamma function which is equal to $n!$ at the integer $n+1$.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

> **I thought it might be instructive to present a way forward that relies on differentiating under the integral.  To that end, we proceed.**

---

Let $I(a)$ be given by the integral

$$I(a)=\int_0^\infty e^{-ax^2}\,x\,dx=\frac1{2a} \tag1$$

Differentiating $(1)$ $n$ times reveals

$$\begin{align}
I^{(n)}(a)&=(-1)^n\int_0^\infty e^{-ax^2}\,x^{2n+1}\,dx\\\\
&=\frac12 \frac{d^n}{da^n}\left(\frac1a\right)\\\\
&=\frac1{2a^{n+1}}(-1)^n\,n!\tag2
\end{align}$$

Finally, setting $a=1$ in $(2)$, we find that

$$\bbox[5px,border:2px solid #C0A000]{\int_0^\infty e^{-x^2}\,x^{2n+1}\,dx=\frac12\,n!}$$

And we are done!

Comment: Should you equation (2) be $\frac{1}{2}(-1)^n \frac{n!}{a^{n+1}}$?

Comment: @strants Indeed.  Good catch.  I've edited.  Thank you.

Answer (score 2):

$n\geq 0$ integer.

$\displaystyle J=\int_{0}^\infty e^{-x^{2}}x^{2n+1}dx$

Perform the change of variable $y=x^2$,

$\begin{align}J&=\frac{1}{2}\int_{0}^\infty e^{-x}x^{n}dx\\
&=\frac{1}{2}\Gamma(n+1)\\
&=\boxed{\frac{1}{2} n!}\\
\end{align}$

Comment: That's the gamma formula you used if I'm not mistaken?

Comment: Sure. It's derived from the  formula, $\Gamma(z+1)=z\Gamma(z)$ and using recurrence.

Answer (score 2):

Let's pretend that we have no idea about the Gamma function. Apply a substitution,

$$t = x^2$$

From which,
$$I_n = \int_0^\infty e^{-t} (x^2)^n \cdot \frac x {2x} \mathrm d t$$
$$I_n = \frac 1 2 \int_0^\infty e^{-t} t^n \mathrm dt$$

As we are trying to prove that $2I_n  = n!$, it is sufficient to prove that, from the recursive definition of the factorial,

$$2I_1 = 1$$
$$I_n = nI_{n-1}$$

Can you take it from here with IBP?

Comment: thanks but I don't get the last factorial part. Any references?

Comment: Apply IBP to $I_{n+1}$ with $f(x)=exp(-t)$, antiderivative $=-exp(-t)$ and $g(t)=t^{n+1}$

Answer (score 2):

Let us start from your initial formula
$$ I_{2n+1} = \int{e^{x^{-2}}}{x^{2n+1}}dx $$
and define the definite integral
$$ J_{2n+1} = \int_0^{\infty}{e^{x^{-2}}}{x^{2n+1}}dx$$

If we take the formula you got via integration by parts:

$$I_{2n+1} = e^{-x^{2}}\frac{x^{2n+2}}{2n+2} +\frac{2}{2n+2} \int{e^{-x^{2}}}{x^{2n+3}}dx$$
and evaluate it at it's limits, it reduces to

$$J_{2n+1} = \frac{1}{n+1} \int_0^{\infty}{e^{-x^{2}}}{x^{2n+3}}dx=\frac{J_{n+3}}{n+1}.$$

Your formula now follows from evaluating $J_1$ and induction.  For this purpose, it is useful to rewrite the equation as $J_{2k+1}=kJ_{2(k-1)+1}$.